# PHP transforming string "&note=" to "¬e="

Tags: php, json, urlencode

```
$to= array();
foreach($users as $v) {
    $to[(string)$v['address']] = (float)($v['amount']*100000);  
}

$guid            = "user";
$main_password   = "pw";
$second_password = "pw2";
$fee             = 60000;
$recipients  = urlencode(json_encode($to));
$from            = "address";
$note            = "public";

$json_url = "https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/sendmany?password=".$main_password."&second_password=".$second_password."&recipients=".$recipients."&shared=false&fee=".$fee."&note=".$note."&from=".$from;

echo $json_url;
die();
```

For some reason, when I `echo $json_url;`, the `&note=` is transformed to `¬e=`. I can't find any PHP or HTML symbol that could be making that transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is `&not;`, or ¬ (mathematical not). Always use `&amp;` to echo out an ampersand (even in URLs) if you're using HTML. Browsers are tolerant of sloppy coding, but in this case it can bite you.

Comment: `$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);` If I wanted to do this, would I still need to use `&amp;`, or would it break the call?

Comment: @user2536244 you only need to escape ampersands if you are echoing them into html. The `file_get_contents` call would be fine.